# Apply if and do in SAS to merge a dataset

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to merge a dataset to another table (hist_dataset) by applying one condition.

The dataset that I'm trying to merge looks like this:

| Label | week_start | date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ac | 09Jan2023 | 13Jan2023 | 45 | 43 |

The logic that I'm using is the next:

If the value("week_start" column) of the first record is equal to today's week + 14 then merge the dataset with the dataset that I want to append.

If the value(week_start column) of the first record is not equal to today's week + 14 then do nothing, don't merge the data.

The code that I'm using is the next:

```
libname out /"path"

data dataset;
     set dataset;
     by week_start;
     if first.week_start = intnx('week.2', today() + 14, 0, 'b') then do;
        data dataset;
        merge out.hist_dataset dataset;
        by label, week_start, date;
        end;
     run;
```

But I'm getting 2 Errors:
117 - 185: There was 1 unclosed DO block.
161 - 185: No matching DO/SELECT statement.

Do you know how can make the program run correctly or do you know another way to do it?

Thanks,

'''

Comment: The first data step ends when SAS sees the start of a second data step.  So the DO has no END.  And in the second data step the END has no DO.  If you want to merge using the current value plus 14 then either use PROC SQL so you can use an expression in the join condition or first create a new variable that has the extra 14 days added and merge using that variable.

Comment: You only show one observation so it is impossible to tell what you want to merge.

Comment: Yes, because I'm just considering the first row to apply the condition.

Comment: Your verbal description is not clear. If you could show the inputs and the expect outputs it might be possible to make a guess at what you are trying to do.  If you only have one observation then what are you merging?  If you just want to remember something from the first row then assign the value to a new variable and retain that variable so its value stays the same on all subsequent observations.

Comment: It is unclear "If the value("week_start" column) of the first record is equal to today's week + 14 then merge the dataset with the dataset that I want to append." - so what can be on next rows ? Are subsequent rows related to the first row?

Comment: APPEND and MERGE are two totally different operations.  Do you want to SUBSET the "append" dataset?  What is the NAME of the VARIABLE in the "append" dataset that has "today's week"  Is it the WEEK variable or the WEEK_START variable?  Do you just want to subset out those observations from that dataset that has the matching date?  Also FIRST. has a specific meaning in SAS code and the FIRST. variables are BOOLEAN (ie 1/0 or True/False) flags.  Simply showing three or four observations from the HIST.xxx dataset and the other dataset and what they result would be would do a long way to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make heads or tails of what you are asking.  So let me take a guess at what you are trying to do and give answer to my guesses.

Let's first make up some dataset and variable names.  So you have an existing dateset named OLD that has key variables LABEL WEEK_START and DATE.

Now you have received a NEW dataset that has those same variables.

You want to first subset the NEW dataset to just those observations where the value of DATE is within 14 days of the first value of START_WEEK in the NEW dataset.

```
data subset ;
  set new;
  if _n_=1 then first_week=start_week;
  retain first_week;
  if date <= first_week+14 ;
run;
```

You then want to merge that into the OLD dataset.

```
data want;
  merge old subset;
  by label week_start date ;
run;
```